# Regex for strings in Bibtex

Tags: regex, variable-assignment, lex

I'm trying to parse Bibtex files using lex/yacc. Strings in the bibtex database can be surrounded by quotes "..." or with braces - {...}

But every entry is also enclosed in braces. How do  differentiate between an entry and a string surrounded by braces?

```
@Book{sweig42,
  Author =   { Stefan Sweig },
  title =    { The impossible book },
  publisher =    { Dead Poet Society},
  year =     1942,
  month =        mar
}
```

Comment: Don't think so. But that can't be used to differentiate the outer {} from the string's {}. The @book definition might not have line breaks.

Comment: Hello, As you are using yacc anyway you may delay the disambiguation until the parsing stage. In that case you are not Limited to regex. Is there a particular requirement to get the Job Done by the lexer? Best regards carsten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have various options:

- lexer start conditions (from a [Lex tutorial](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/lex/index.html))

  building on the ideas from [greg ward](http://search.cpan.org/~gward/btparse-0.34/doc/bt_language.pod), enhance your lex rules with start conditions ('modes' as they are called    in the referenced source).

specifically, you would have the start conditions `BASIC ENTRY STRING` and the following rules (example taken and slightly enhanced from [here](http://search.cpan.org/~gward/btparse-0.34/doc/bt_language.pod)):

```
%START BASIC ENTRY STRING
%%

/* Lexical grammar, mode 1: top-level */
<BASIC>AT           @ { BEGIN ENTRY; }
<BASIC>NEWLINE      \n
<BASIC>COMMENT      \%[^\n]*\n
<BASIC>WHITESPACE.  [\ \r\t]+
<BASIC>JUNK         [^@\n\ \r\t]+

/* Lexical grammar, mode 2: in-entry */
<ENTRY>NEWLINE      \n
<ENTRY>COMMENT      \%[^\n]*\n
<ENTRY>WHITESPACE   [\ \r\t]+
<ENTRY>NUMBER       [0-9]+
<ENTRY>NAME         [a-z0-9\!\$\&\*\+\-\.\/\:\;\<\>\?\[\]\^\_\`\|]+ { if (stricmp(yytext, "comment")==0) { BEGIN STRING; } }
<ENTRY>LBRACE       \{ { if (delim == '\0') { delim='}'; } else { blevel=1; BEGIN STRING; } }
<ENTRY>RBRACE       \} { BEGIN BASIC; }
<ENTRY>LPAREN       \( { BEGIN STRING; delim=')'; plevel=1; }
<ENTRY>RPAREN       \)
<ENTRY>EQUALS       =
<ENTRY>HASH         \#
<ENTRY>COMMA        ,
<ENTRY>QUOTE        \" { BEGIN STRING; bleveL=0; plevel=0; }

/* Lexical grammar, mode 3: strings */
<STRING>LBRACE       \{ { if (blevel>0) {blevel++;} }
<STRING>RBRACE       \} { if (blevel>0) { blevel--; if (blevel == 0) { BEGIN ENTRY; } } }
<STRING>LPAREN       \( { if (plevel>0) { plevel++;} }
<STRING>RPAREN       \} { if (plevel>0) { plevel--; if (plevel == 0) { BEGIN ENTRY; } } }
<STRING>QUOTE        \" { BEGIN ENTRY; }
```

please note that the rule set is by no means complete but should get you started. more details to be found [here](http://search.cpan.org/~gward/btparse-0.34/doc/bt_language.pod).

- btparse

  [These docs](http://search.cpan.org/~gward/btparse-0.34/doc/bt_language.pod) explain in a fairly detailed fashion thenintricacies of parsing the bibtex formats and comes with a 'python parser.
- biblex

  you might also be interested in employing the unix toolchain of biblex and bibparse. these tools generate and parse a bibtex token stream, respectively.

  more info can be found [here](http://www.math.utah.edu/~beebe/software/bibparse/bibparse.html).

best regards, carsten

Comment: Great! But the assignment was due a month back - so I figured out something like your code. Multiple states and keeping track of braces/parentheses.